# Проблема с доступом с СУБД PostgreSQL из приложения Delphi посредством ODBC

Tags: delphi, postgresql, ado, odbc

Пытаюсь получить доступ к БД postgresSQL из Delphi Seattle через ODBC драйвер.

Получаю ошибку: [image: error]

Везде в интернетах написано, что это из-за того, что приложение собрано как 32битное, а драйвер используется 64 битный. Но у и драйвер 64битный, и приложение, как видно на скриншоте, собрано под win64. Я уже в отчаянии(( Не понимаю, в чём проблема((

DSN:

[image: error2]

Comment: Запускаете под дебагом? DSN точно 64-битный, а не 32-битный настроен?

Comment: kami, не запускаю, это design-time настройка.

Comment: DSN 64битный. Прикрепил фото.

Comment: `это design-time настройка` так Delphi всю жизнь был 32-битный. Вот вам и несоответствие. В runtime все должно быть хорошо :)

Comment: kami ну привет( А как я в design-time буду DB-Aware контролы настраивать? Я не могу создать поля запроса, не могу привязать их к колонкам в гриде. Работать невозможно.

Comment: Кто мешает создать 32битный dsn?

Comment: Окей, попробую так. Скачал 32битный ODBC драйвер.https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/ Установил(.msi файл). В списке DSN 32битная версия не появилась. Как это сделать?

Comment: %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/942976

Comment: kami уху! Спасибо! Соединение установлено! Один вопрос остался - у DataSource есть свойство DataSet, в которое, в теории, должен назначаться компонент TADOStoredProc, TADOQuery, или любой другой, который сосёт данные из базы. На практике туда встаёт только TADODataSet. А мне нужен TADOStoredProc. Как его подружить с TDataSource?

Comment: `Один вопрос остался` - так задайте его! На stackoverflow принято именно так: одна тема - один вопрос. Уточнения - в комментаниях, ответы - в ответах :)

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что `Embarcadero RAD Studio` уже достаточно давно имеет возможность создавать 64-битные приложения, сама среда разработки остается 32-битной.

Поэтому, если необходимо в design-time использовать подключение к БД через ODBC, необходимо настроить 32-битное подключение (и не забыть, что в runtime будет использоваться 64-битное для 64-битных приложений). В 64-битной Windows для этого необходимо запустить `%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64\Odbcad32.exe`

Подробнее: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/942976